# How to eliminate a annoying amount of white space between bars in bar plot?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have removed one row of data from a file, but I cannot find way to get rid of the white space in the center of the plot. Reducing the width moves the bars outside of the graph, and the only way to get decent cosmetics has been to enlarge the width to a unreasonable value. How to correct this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{document}

%==========================
\begin{filecontents}{data0.csv}
{Product-Code},{Total parts},{Active parts}
{0728}, 2414,0
{0510},9931,1510
\end{filecontents}
%===========================
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data0.csv}{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=6cm, width=12 cm,
%grid=both,
ybar,
enlarge y limits={value= 0.3, upper},
enlarge x limits=true,
bar width=20pt,
xtick=data,
x tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
xticklabels=data,
xticklabels from table={\datatable}{[index]0},
%every even column/.append style={column sep=1cm},
nodes near coords, every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize, /pgf/number format/fixed,
/pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace },
title={Number of parts per product code},
xlabel={PRODUCT CODE},
ymin=0,
ytick style={draw=none},
scaled y ticks = false,
yticklabels={\empty},
legend style={nodes=right},
legend pos= north west,
legend entries={ Active, Total},
]
\addplot [fill=orange!80, draw=cyan!50!black] table [
x expr=\coordindex,
y index=2] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=cyan!80, draw=cyan!50!black] table [
x expr=\coordindex,
y index=1] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%============================

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reducing the `width` you need to adjust `enlarge x limits` judiciously:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{document}

%==========================
\begin{filecontents}{data0.csv}
{Product-Code},{Total parts},{Active parts}
{0728}, 2414,0
{0510},9931,1510
\end{filecontents}
%===========================
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data0.csv}{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[height=6cm, width=5.5 cm,
    % grid=both,
    ybar,
    enlarge y limits={value=0.3, upper},
    enlarge x limits=0.4,
    bar width=20pt,
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
    xticklabels=data,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{[index]0},
    nodes near coords, every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize, /pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace },
    title={Number of parts per product code},
    xlabel={PRODUCT CODE},
    ymin=0,
    ytick style={draw=none},
    scaled y ticks = false,
    yticklabels={\empty},
    legend style={nodes=right},
    legend pos= north west,
    legend entries={ Active, Total},
    ]
    \addplot [fill=orange!80, draw=cyan!50!black] table [
    x expr=\coordindex,
    y index=2] {\datatable};
    \addplot [fill=cyan!80, draw=cyan!50!black] table [
    x expr=\coordindex,
    y index=1] {\datatable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%============================

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it's not that ugly but also not so elegant. However, your width is the actual culprit.

Since you are using `\coordindex` for x values

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
{Product-Code},{Total parts},{Active parts}
0728, 2414,0
0510,9931,1510
}{\datatable}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\let\myrowno\pgfplotsretval

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=6cm, 
            width=12 cm,
            ybar,
            enlarge y limits={value= 0.3, upper},
            %enlarge x limits=true,
            bar width=20pt,
            xtick={0,...,\myrowno},xmax=\myrowno,xmin=-1,
            x tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
            xticklabels=data,
            xticklabels from table={\datatable}{[index]0},
            nodes near coords, 
            every node near coord/.append style={
                font=\footnotesize, /pgf/number format/fixed,
                /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace 
                },
            title={Number of parts per product code},
            xlabel={PRODUCT CODE},
            ymin=0,
            ytick style={draw=none},
            scaled y ticks = false,
            yticklabels={\empty},
            legend style={nodes=right},
            legend pos= north west,
            legend entries={ Active, Total},
]
\addplot [fill=orange!80, draw=cyan!50!black] table [x expr=\coordindex,y index=2] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=cyan!80, draw=cyan!50!black] table [x expr=\coordindex,y index=1] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]